# Qual a diferença entre Action, Predicate e Func

Tags: c#, .net, expressões-lambda

Qual a diferença entre `Action`, `Predicate` e `Func` no C#?

Gostaria, se possível, de exemplos de uso.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## `Func`

[`Func`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-2?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0) é usado para determinar um `delegate`. Ou seja é para tipar (criar uma assinatura) uma função anônima. Nele é especificado os tipos de diversos parâmetros e o tipo do retorno da função.

```
var operacoes = new Dictionary<string, Func<int, int, int>> {
    {"+", (op1, op2) => op1 + op2 },
    {"-", (op1, op2) => op1 - op2 },
    {"*", (op1, op2) => op1 * op2 },
    {"/", (op1, op2) => op1 / op2 }
};
Write(operacoes["+"](10, 20)); //imprime 30
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Lambda/Func.cs).

neste caso a função terá dois parâmetros inteiros e seu retorno também será um inteiro.

## `Action`

[`Action`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action-1?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0) é uma `Func` que não terá um retorno, ou seja, é função anônima que retorna nada (seria o tipo `void`). Ela faz uma ação ao invés de dar um resultado, como costuma acontecer com funções.

```
var acoes = new Dictionary<string, Action<int>> {
    {"Criar", (parametro) => Criar(parametro) },
    {"Editar", (parametro) => Editar(parametro) },
    {"Apagar", (parametro) => Apagar(parametro) },
    {"Imprimir", (parametro) => Imprimir(parametro) }
};
acoes["Criar"](1); //executará o método Criar
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Lambda/Action.cs).

A função terá um parâmetro inteiro.

## `Predicate`

[`Predicate`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.predicate-1?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0) é uma `Func` que retorna um `bool`. Hoje ele não é muito necessário. `Func` resolve bem. Só use se quiser realmente indicar que aquilo não é uma função qualquer, mas sim um predicado (critério para um filtro). `Predicate` só pode ter um parâmetro. Os dois tipos anteriores permitem até 16 parâmetros já que existem vários tipos com assinaturas diferentes.

```
var compareZero = new Dictionary<string, Predicate<int>> {
    {">", (x) => x > 0 },
    {"<", (x) => x < 0 },
    {"=", (x) => x == 0 }
};
Write(compareZero["="](5)); //imprimirá False
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Lambda/Predicate.cs).

Os exemplos são obviamente simplificados e sem contexto.

Eles são especialmente úteis com LINQ.

Comment: Perfeito, muito obrigado