# Delegates e métodos

Tags: c#, método, delegate

Quando usar *delegates*?

Sendo que um *delegate* aponta para um método, não é a mesma coisa que criar um método normal?

- Qual a diferença e quando usar e porquê usar?
- É melhor?
- É pior?

Answer (score 5):

O *delegate* é atribuído a uma variável ou passado como argumento de um método (que chegará em uma variável), ou ainda como retorno. Não é possível fazer isso com um método normal (até dá mas não da forma normal e de forma mais simples). Então esse é o motivo para utilizá-lo. Ele é útil quando precisa tratar um determinado código como dado, quando precisa "armazenar" o código em alguma variável.

E o termo variável aí é importante, já que pode trocar o dado quando quiser, ou seja, pode trocar qual é o código que deverá ser executado quando essa variável é executada (sim, nesse caso é possível chamar a variável, inclusive passando argumentos para ela, exatamente como se faz com um método).

Então, como o próprio nome diz, você está delegando a execução para algum código a ser determinado. De certa forma podemos dizer que é um método virtual definido em tempo de execução. Ele dá muita flexibilidade ao objeto que usa esse recurso. O consumidor do objeto pode determinar que comportamento quer dar a um determinado *slot*.

Não é nem melhor, nem pior, é diferente. Quando precisa "parametrizar" qual é o código a ser executado ele é muito útil. Quando precisa ter uma função de *callback*, [muito comum no uso de eventos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56957/101), por exemplo. Sempre dá para fazer de outra forma, mas com ele é mais fácil.

Um *delegate* é uma classe especial que possui um ponteiro para um código (pode até ser um método comum) entre outras facilidades. No C# o *delegate* precisa ter uma [assinatura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39870/101) específica e qualquer (ponteiro para um) código que seja armazenado nele deve atender essa assinatura.

O `delegate` é um tipo que pode ser declarado para uso posterior, mas também pode usar [alguns pré-definidos que serão parametrizados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90058/101).

Veja mais em [Como declarar uma função dentro de outra função em C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/130191/101), [Qual a diferença entre uma expressão lambda, um closure e um delegate?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/34907/101) e [Quando e onde usar um delegate no C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101238/101).

- [Documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397)

Exemplo:

```
class Exemplo {
    public Func<bool> VerificaAlgo { get; set; }
    public void FazAlgo() {
        if (VerificaAlgo()) WriteLine("é apenas um teste");
        else WriteLine("a coisa é séria");
    }
}

class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        Exemplo teste = new Exemplo();
        teste.VerificaAlgo = new Func<bool>(() => ReadLine() == "teste");
        teste.FazAlgo();
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/w8QO4a). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rifqvw). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Lambda/DelegateXMethod.cs).

Outro:

```
public Cliente Ache(Predicate<Customer> condicao) {
    foreach (var cliente in lista.Clientes)
       if (condicao(cliente))
          return cliente;
}
```

Uso:

```
clientes.Ache(cliente => cliente.Nome.StartsWith("M"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Eventos são do tipo `MulticastDelegate`, um tipo de delegate que invoca múltiplas funções.

Linq usa `delegates` para determinar predicados.

Entre outros exemplos.

Usa-se quando é preciso um tipo de processamento personalizado, sem que se saiba previamente (em tempo de desenvolvimento) o que a função vai realizar. Isso pode ser atribuído em tempo de execução até mesmo por outro assembly, você referencia `System.Windows.Forms` e atribui um handler para um evento de um controle, por exemplo. Sem delegates seria necessário herdar a classe e sobrescrever os métodos, acho que isso é mais uma questão de gosto pessoal, por que dá mais ou menos o mesmo trabalho, é o conceito de linguagem de multi-paradigma.

Além disso, delegates podem ser atribuídos ou anulados, desativando facilmente alguma funcionalidade sem a necessidade de conferências.

Eu particularmente só utilizo delegates quanto há algum processamento multi-caso, ao invés de escrever um monte de `if` ou `switch` e selecionar a função em toda execução, você atribui a função ao delegate e o invoca. E também para transmitir sinais entre objetos, principalmente com operações concorrentes.