# O que é o method group?

Tags: c#, .net, método

Codificando em C# acabei cometendo um erro, talvez por familiaridade com outras linguagens que costumo trabalhar, e esqueci dos parênteses.

```
string.Concat(numero.ToString, "A")
```

Recebi o seguinte erro:

> cannot convert from 'method group' to 'object'

Eu até fui pesquisar sobre o que é esse *method group*, mas como é um conceito que nunca vi em outra linguagem não compreendi totalmente a finalidade dele, ou o porquê dele existir.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Não sei se já entende que os métodos possuem *overloads* ([assinaturas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39870/101)), então como existem vários métodos com o mesmo nome, eles formam um grupo. Obviamente o grupo pode ser formado por apenas um método se ele tiver apenas uma assinatura.

Isso foi uma ideia muito interessante originalmente criada para facilitar o uso de [delegados, e consequentemente dos eventos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56957/101), assim qualquer dos métodos pode ser associado com o delegado diretamente. Depois [*lambdas*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/34907/101) foram beneficiadas também.

Se o parâmetro do método `Concat()` hipoteticamente esperasse um delegado, então funcionaria. Claro que isso não faria sentido.

`ToString()` é um método, `ToString` é um grupo de método, portanto são duas coisas bem distintas. Tem linguagem que é apenas uma simplificação de sintaxe por não existir esse conceito novo.

Em todo lugar que aceita um delegado você pode criá-lo de várias maneiras:

```
Action<string> x = delegate(string txt) { WriteLine(txt); };
```

Essa é a forma inicial do C# e é quase obsoleta, substituída por:

```
Action<string> x = txt => WriteLine(txt);
```

Ou pode usar um *method group*:

```
Action<string> x = WriteLine;
```

De acordo com a assinatura do delegado o método referenciado, no caso o `WriteLine()`, com a assinatura equivalente será chamado.

Usando como referência de um delegado:

```
using System;
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var numero = 123;
        Func<string, string> func = numero.ToString;
        WriteLine(func("000000"));
        Func<string> func2 = numero.ToString;
        WriteLine(func2());
        Action<string> a = delegate(string txt) { WriteLine(txt); };
        Action<string> b = txt => WriteLine(txt);
        Action<string> c = WriteLine;
        a("abc");
        b("abc");
        c("abc");
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Ac8gfL). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YxKp8b). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Method/MethodGroup.cs).

Se tiver curiosidade em ler a [especificação da linguagem](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/expressions.md), tem informações bem detalhadas de como funciona, esse capítulo é um texto bem curtinho :P

Comment: E o que seria o delegado nessas linhas?

Comment: Ah, é o `Func<>` e `Action<>`. Esse são tipos que facilitam a declaração de delegados. De outra forma teria que declará-los em outro local para uso, fica imprático. Isso existe desde o C# 3. Pode ver mais em http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90058/101