# Usando Concat para concatenar array de strings

Tags: c#, .net, string

Estava vendo sobre *strings* e que elas são imutáveis e não pode ficar adicionando nelas em quantidade sob pena de ficar muito lento.

A recomendação é usar o `StringBuilder`. Mas também vi que existe uma versão do [Concat()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0wkb0y3w(v=vs.110).aspx) que aceita um array.

Não seria o caso de usá-lo?

Comment: Viu que eu usei o *method group* passando no `Time()`? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/189905/101. No caso o grupo só tem um método, mas não deixa de ser um grupo.

Comment: @bigown Entendi. Ficou bem claro, obrigado!

Answer (score 6):

Provavelmente o que leu foi uma "boa prática" (que eu sou um crítico). Eu mesmo caio nessa besteira quando vou escrever porque nem sempre temos tempo para explicar todos os detalhes, mas se a pessoa aceita afirmação de alguém sem um contexto está apenas seguindo as tais das "boas práticas" e pode desde não ter o resultado esperado, como aquilo pode ser o oposto e se tornar uma péssima prática.

De fato o [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0) é recomendado quando tem que adicionar várias *strings* em uma só. Porém se esta operação for a única e não tem que fazer outras ações no laço então não precisa usar o `StringBuilder`, até porque eu acho que o `Concat()` usa um `StringBuilder` internamente, assim consegue um código *one liner*.

Mas vamos ter certeza e fazer um *benchmark*:

```
using System;
using static System.Console;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text;

public class Program {
    const int Limit = 100000;
    static int[] dataInt = new int[Limit];
    static string[] dataString = new string[Limit];

    public static void Main() {
        for (int i = 0; i < Limit; i++) {
            dataInt[i] = i;
            dataString[i] = i.ToString();
        }
        Time(ConcatenationInt);
        Time(JunctionInt);
        Time(BuilderInt);
        Time(AdditionInt);
        Time(ConcatenationString);
        Time(JunctionString);
        Time(BuilderString);
        Time(AdditionString);
    }

    static void Time(Func<int> action) {
        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        int result = action();
        sw.Stop();
        WriteLine($"{result} - {sw.ElapsedTicks:000,000,000} - {action.Method.Name}");
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    }

    static int AdditionInt() {
        var tmp = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < Limit; i++) tmp += dataInt[i];
        return tmp.Length;            
    }

    static int AdditionString() {
        var tmp = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < Limit; i++) tmp += dataString[i];
        return tmp.Length;
    }

    static int ConcatenationInt() => string.Concat(dataInt).Length;

    static int ConcatenationString() => string.Concat(dataString).Length;

    static int JunctionInt() => string.Join("", dataInt).Length;

    static int JunctionString() => string.Join("", dataString).Length;

    static int BuilderInt() {
        var tmp = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < Limit; i++) tmp.Append(dataInt[i]);
        return tmp.Length;            
    }

    static int BuilderString() {
        var tmp = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < Limit; i++) tmp.Append(dataString[i]);
        return tmp.Length;            
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/173LZ2). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/usvJJU). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/ConcatXStringBuilder.cs).

O ideal é fazer o teste em sua máquina sem nada afetando a execução. Testes em ambientes compartilhados como esses usados acima não são válidos. Tentei minimizar o efeito do GC, mas não tem jeito neste ambiente de memória restrita.

A conclusão que dá para tirar é que em caso assim a concatenação é ótima, a junção também, e a construção da *string* é uma opção quase tão boa, só a adição individual é que é trágica.

[O código do `Concat()`pode ser visto](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,40825b9a6e8f4b1e) e ele faz algo até um pouco mais inteligente que o `StringBuilder`. [No .NET Core](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,40825b9a6e8f4b1e).