# HTML dentro de um StringBuilder

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, .net, string

Tenho um HTML onde estou formatando ele dentro de um `StringBuilder`, onde tem “aspas” estou passando uma barra, mais não está abrindo o HTML correto.

```
public string CorpoPaginaHtml()
        {
            StringBuilder corpoemail = new StringBuilder();
            corpoemail.AppendLine("");
            corpoemail.AppendLine("< !DOCTYPE html >");
            corpoemail.AppendLine("< html lang = \"pt_BR\"> ");
            corpoemail.AppendLine("< head > ");
            corpoemail.AppendLine("< meta charset = \"utf-8\" >");
            corpoemail.AppendLine("< meta http - equiv = \"X-UA-Compatible\" content = \"IE=edge\" >");
            corpoemail.AppendLine("< meta name = \"viewport\" content = \"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\" >");
            corpoemail.AppendLine("< title > Aviso de Produto</ title >");
            corpoemail.AppendLine("< link rel = \"stylesheet\" href = \"http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css\" > ");
            corpoemail.AppendLine("< script src = \"http://imsky.github.com/holder/holder.js\" ></ script > ");
            corpoemail.AppendLine("</ head >");
            corpoemail.AppendLine("< body >");
            corpoemail.AppendLine(" < div class=\"container\" >");
            corpoemail.AppendLine("< hr />");
            corpoemail.AppendLine("<h2>Aviso de Produto</h2>");
            corpoemail.AppendLine("< div class=\"row\">");
            corpoemail.AppendLine("<div id = \"items -list\" class=\"col-xs-8\">");
            corpoemail.AppendLine("<div class=\"media\">");
            corpoemail.AppendLine("<a class=\"media -left\" href=\"#\">");
            corpoemail.AppendLine("<img alt = \"64x64\" width=\"150\" height=\"100\"  src=\"http://media.webdevacademy.com.br/2014/02/placeholder.jpg\">");
            corpoemail.AppendLine("</a>");
            corpoemail.AppendLine("< div class=\"media -body\">");
            corpoemail.AppendLine(" <h4 class=\"media -heading\">Titulo</h4>");
            corpoemail.AppendLine(" Cras sit amet nibh libero, in gravida nulla.Nulla vel metus scelerisque ante sollicitudin commodo. Cras purus odio, vestibulum in vulputate at, tempus viverra turpis.Fusce condimentum nunc ac nisi vulputate fringilla.Donec lacinia congue felis in faucibus.");
            corpoemail.AppendLine("</div>");
            corpoemail.AppendLine("</div>");
            corpoemail.AppendLine(" </div>");
            corpoemail.AppendLine("</div>");
            corpoemail.AppendLine("<hr />");
            corpoemail.AppendLine("< footer class\"footer -inverse\">");
            corpoemail.AppendLine(" <div class=\"container\">");
            corpoemail.AppendLine("<p class=\"text -muted\">&copy;2017 - Modelo Exemplo Onofre.</p>");
            corpoemail.AppendLine(" </div>");
            corpoemail.AppendLine(" </footer>");
            corpoemail.AppendLine(" <script src = \"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js\" ></ script > ");
            corpoemail.AppendLine(" <script src = \"http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js\" ></ script > ");
            corpoemail.AppendLine(" </ body >");
            corpoemail.AppendLine("</ html >");

            return corpoemail.ToString(); 
        }
```

Comment: Qual é o problema? O que você quer dizer com "**não está abrindo o HTML correto**"?

Comment: `< footer class\"footer -inverse\">"` está faltando o sinal `=` por ex.
acho que voce tem que revisar seu HTML

Comment: Pra que usar `StringBuilder`?

Comment: Alguma resposta resolveu o que estava em dúvida? Precisa que algo mais seja melhorado? Acha que é possível aceitá-la agora?

Answer (score 3):

Não precisa dessa complicação e desperdício de processamento todo, pode ser simples assim:

```
public class Program {
    public static void Main()   {
        var html = @"<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang = ""pt_BR""> 
        <head> 
        <meta charset = ""utf-8"">
        <meta http-equiv = ""X-UA-Compatible"" content = ""IE=edge"">
        <meta name = ""viewport"" content = ""width=device-width, initial-scale=1"">
        <title> Aviso de Produto</title>
        <link rel = ""stylesheet"" href = ""http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css""> 
        <script src = ""http://imsky.github.com/holder/holder.js""></script> 
        </head>
        <body>
         <div class=""container"">
        <hr/>
        <h2>Aviso de Produto</h2>
        <div class=""row"">
        <div id = ""items-list"" class=""col-xs-8"">
        <div class=""media"">
        <a class=""media -left"" href=""#"">
        <img alt = ""64x64"" width=""150"" height=""100""  src=""http://media.webdevacademy.com.br/2014/02/placeholder.jpg"">
        </a>
        <div class=""media-body"">
         <h4 class=""media-heading"">Titulo</h4>
         Cras sit amet nibh libero, in gravida nulla.Nulla vel metus scelerisque ante sollicitudin commodo. Cras purus odio, vestibulum in vulputate at, tempus viverra turpis.Fusce condimentum nunc ac nisi vulputate fringilla.Donec lacinia congue felis in faucibus.
        </div>
        </div>
         </div>
        </div>
        <hr/>
        <footer class""footer-inverse"">
         <div class=""container"">
        <p class=""text-muted"">&copy;2017 - Modelo Exemplo Onofre.</p>
         </div>
         </footer>
         <script src = ""https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js""></script> 
         <script src = ""http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js""></script> 
         </body>
        </html>";
        System.Console.WriteLine(html);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Azhf0P). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pVszVD). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/VerbatimMultiLineEscapeQuotes.cs).

O código está cheio de erros, aparentemente eu corrigi todos eles.

Mesmo que insista em usar o [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) pelo menos inicie a capacidade de com um tamanho estimado do texto, sei lá, 512, 1024 pra melhorar a performance e colocar menos pressão no GC.

[image: HTML correto]

Comment: deu certo, agora como eu poderia concatenar uma variável dentro do html? agradeço a ajuda

Comment: Se for só uma ou algumas variáveis é só usar o `+`, isso será transformando em `Contact()` e será eficiente. O problema só ocorrerá se usar um em *loop*, fazer várias concatenações desta forma fica ruim, mas precisa ser várias mesmo. Veja http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/191264/101

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro, as tags não podem ter espaço entre os sinais **`<`**, **`>`** e o nome da tag e isso é feito em quase todas as linhas.

Segundo, tem outros lugares com espaços como em `meta http-equiv` isso não pode.

Terceiro problema, no `footer class "footer -inverse"` falta o sinal de atribuição.

Revise todo o seu HTML, aqui vai uma base, já dá pra visualizar o resultado, mas ainda tem erros.

```
public string CorpoPaginaHtml()
{
    StringBuilder corpoemail = new StringBuilder();
    corpoemail.AppendLine("");
    corpoemail.AppendLine("<!DOCTYPE html>");
    corpoemail.AppendLine("<html lang=\"pt_BR\"> ");
    corpoemail.AppendLine("<head> ");
    corpoemail.AppendLine("<meta charset=\"utf-8\">");
    corpoemail.AppendLine("<meta http-equiv = \"X-UA-Compatible\" content = \"IE=edge\">");
    corpoemail.AppendLine("<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\">");
    corpoemail.AppendLine("<title>Aviso de Produto</title>");
    corpoemail.AppendLine("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css\"> ");
    corpoemail.AppendLine("<script src = \"http://imsky.github.com/holder/holder.js\"></script> ");
    corpoemail.AppendLine("</head>");
    corpoemail.AppendLine("<body>");
    corpoemail.AppendLine(" <div class=\"container\">");
    corpoemail.AppendLine("<hr/>");
    corpoemail.AppendLine("<h2>Aviso de Produto</h2>");
    corpoemail.AppendLine("<div class=\"row\">");
    corpoemail.AppendLine("<div id = \"items-list\" class=\"col-xs-8\">");
    corpoemail.AppendLine("<div class=\"media\">");
    corpoemail.AppendLine("<a class=\"media-left\" href=\"#\">");
    corpoemail.AppendLine("<img alt=\"64x64\" width=\"150\" height=\"100\"  src=\"http://media.webdevacademy.com.br/2014/02/placeholder.jpg\">");
    corpoemail.AppendLine("</a>");
    corpoemail.AppendLine("<div class=\"media-body\">");
    corpoemail.AppendLine(" <h4 class=\"media-heading\">Titulo</h4>");
    corpoemail.AppendLine(" Cras sit amet nibh libero, in gravida nulla.Nulla vel metus scelerisque ante sollicitudin commodo. Cras purus odio, vestibulum in vulputate at, tempus viverra turpis.Fusce condimentum nunc ac nisi vulputate fringilla.Donec lacinia congue felis in faucibus.");
    corpoemail.AppendLine("</div>");
    corpoemail.AppendLine("</div>");
    corpoemail.AppendLine(" </div>");
    corpoemail.AppendLine("</div>");
    corpoemail.AppendLine("<hr/>");
    corpoemail.AppendLine("<footer class=\"footer -inverse\">");
    corpoemail.AppendLine(" <div class=\"container\">");
    corpoemail.AppendLine("<p class=\"text -muted\">&copy;2017 - Modelo Exemplo Onofre.</p>");
    corpoemail.AppendLine(" </div>");
    corpoemail.AppendLine(" </footer>");
    corpoemail.AppendLine(" <script src = \"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js\"></script> ");
    corpoemail.AppendLine(" <script src = \"http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js\"></script> ");
    corpoemail.AppendLine(" </body>");
    corpoemail.AppendLine("</html>");

    return corpoemail.ToString(); 
}
```

Comment: tem um monte de erros o html dele... `<div id = \"items -list\" class=\"col-xs-8\">"` por isso sugeri ele revisar o html todo ..

Comment: @andrepaulo Pronto

Comment: @jbueno, muito agradecido, eu vou revisar

Comment: @jbueno, deu certo, agora como eu poderia concatenar uma variável dentro do html? agradeço a ajuda

Comment: Usa a concatenação normal de strings. @itasouza