# Como usar e pra que serve a função timer no C#?

Tags: c#, .net, timer

```
//Exemplo de uso(Que não entendi):
using System;
using System.Threading;

public static class Program {

   public static void Main() {
      // Create a Timer object that knows to call our TimerCallback
      // method once every 2000 milliseconds.
      Timer t = new Timer(TimerCallback, null, 0, 2000);
      // Wait for the user to hit <Enter>
      Console.ReadLine();
   }

   private static void TimerCallback(Object o) {
      // Display the date/time when this method got called.
      Console.WriteLine("In TimerCallback: " + DateTime.Now);
      // Force a garbage collection to occur for this demo.
      GC.Collect();
   }
}
```

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 2):

`Timer` não é uma função, é uma classe que provê um mecanismo que permite especificar uma frequência de tempo que uma determinada operação deve ser executada.

Assim cria-se o objeto configurando o que deve ser executado através de um delegado e quando executar (`TimerCallback`).

Pode-se passar um objeto para que esse delegado possa processar, mas no exemplo postado passa um nulo, já que nada é necessário (`null`). Ele é do tipo `object` para dar liberdade de passar qualquer coisa. Isto é entre o seu código que configura o `Timer`, no caso o `Main()`, e o método que funcionará como um *callback*, no caso o `TimerCallback()`

Também passa-se um tempo que deve demorar para executar a primeira vez, sendo o 0 o início imediato, que é o que foi passado.

E passa-se o intervalo entre cada execução, no caso 2000 passado é 2 segundos já que a medida é em milissegundos.

Na mesma classe existem outras formas de configurar de forma diferente dependendo da conveniência do momento. Isso é efeito com várias [sobrecargas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/137185/101) de [construtores](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101).

Sempre procure a [documentação oficial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-8.0) para aprender sobre uma classe ou método dela. Nela sempre tem a explicação do que faz, o que significa cada parte dele e costuma ter um exemplo de uso e alguns cuidados.

Entenda o que é um [delegado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56957/101) e um [grupo de métodos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/189905/101) e aprenda porque só passa o nome do método e mais nada. [Mais uma pergunta sobre o assunto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/116095/101).

Veja [o que é *callback*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/27177/101), o foco é outra linguagem, mas a técnica é a mesma.

Não é o caso, mas existem outras classes de [`Timer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-8.0) com um mecanismo um pouco diferente.

O método delegado potencialmente chama o coletor de lixo. Isso [não deve ser feito em condições normais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/110854/101). Se é um curso que ensina isso, considere um alerta vermelho do conteúdo, a não ser que exista um contexto e explicação porque existe isto.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, vamos ao seu código de exemplo.

```
Timer t = new Timer(TimerCallback, null, 0, 2000);
```

O primeiro parâmetro `(TimerCallback)` você está chamando a função `private static void TimerCallback(Object o)` para iniciar sempre que o timer bater os 2 segundos, ou seja, ele será executado de 2 em 2 segundos (seguindo no seu exemplo).

O segundo parâmetro `(null)` é o estado do seu timer, no seu caso o timer nunca vai parar, porque é nulo.

O terceiro parâmetro, é quando o timer vai executar o `TimerCallback` no seu exemplo, vai executar sempre que estiver 0ms.

O quarto parâmetro, é o tempo de intervalo do timer, no seu exemplo `(2000ms)`, ele executará a cada 2 segundos. Ou seja ele começará do 0 e quando der 2000ms novamente, ele voltará a 0.

Comment: Acho que tem umas coisas erradas aí, ou está um pouco confuso.

Comment: Pois é, utilizei TimerCallback somente 1 vez, quando fui escrever, fiquei em dúvida em algumas coisas, mas escrevi do mesmo jeito para tentar ajudar.