# Como fazer um cronômetro com precisão de milissegundos?

Tags: c#

Olá, sou iniciante e decidi criar uma função de cronômetro para praticar algumas técnicas. O cronômetro pode marcar o tempo de forma descendente (ex: 10,9,8,7,6,5) ou ascendente (9,10,11,12), além de o usuário poder escolher os intervalos de inicio e fim. Porém, apesar de o meu código estar funcionando perfeitamente para cronometrar segundos e, ao meu ver, estando bastante limpo e conciso, o tempo de execução e processamento das linhas de código impossibilita qualquer tentativa de cronometrar milésimos com alguma acurácia. Gostaria de saber se existe alguma maneira de optimizá-lo ou se há alguma função que desconheço e que poderia ser aplicada nesse caso. Desde já, agradeço.

```
    class Timer
{
    private int _delay;

    public int Delay { set { _delay = value >= 0 ? value : 0; } }

    public void Counting(int initialValue, int finalValue)
    {
        int start = DateTime.Now.Second + _delay;
        int countingValue = initialValue;

        int i = 0;
        while (initialValue <= finalValue ? countingValue <= finalValue : countingValue >= finalValue)
        {
            start = start + i == 60 ? - i : start;

            if (DateTime.Now.Second == start + i)
            {

                Display(countingValue);

               countingValue = initialValue <= finalValue ? countingValue + 1 : countingValue - 1;

                i++;

            }
        }

    }

    public void Display(int countingValue)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(countingValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: Primeiro, não precisa de uma classe para fazer isto. Um método resolve seu problema com uma pequena alteração. Só crie classes se precisa delas. Se não tem um motivo para ter uma uma, não crie. A não ser que queira fazer outra coisa, mas só podemos avaliar o que está no seu código e o que colocou que deseja fazer. Depois, essa á a pior forma de tentar fazer isso. Fica o processador trabalhando como louco para um resultado desprezível. Tem algumas respostas aqui que ajudam: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86014/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/211902/101.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela sua resposta, @Maniero♦. Lendo os links que você sugeriu, aprendi um pouco sobre métodos async e consegui implementar o "await Task.Delay();" no meu código. A única coisa que não compreendi muito bem foi essa questão de evitar criar novas classes. Seria possível criar um método isoladamente (sem estar dentro de uma classe), ou você estava se referindo a colocar esse método dentro da classe onde se encontra o Main?

Comment: Em C# 9 é totalmente possível, antes disso já era possível criar classe estática que não é uma classe de verdade. E claro pode ser junto do `Main()`, mas não necessariamente.

Answer (score 0):

Para não deixar essa questão em aberto caso alguém com o mesmo problema encontre esse post, irei responder com o que aprendi pelos posts sugeridos do @Maniero♦.

A forma de funcionamento do meu código antigo exigia constantes checagem de passagem de tempo e isso exigia não só poder de processamento, como também lentificava a verificação (sendo perceptível principalmente quando se trabalhava com milissegundos). Existem formas de atingir um resultado melhor e com menos comprometimentos usando assincronicidade e o método `Task.Delay()`.

Para isso, é necessário adicionar o modificador `async` no seu método e utilizar o `await Task.Delay()` para realizar a espera.

O código corrigido para essa formatação seria:

```
 public static async void Counting(int initialValue, int finalValue, int delayMiliseconds)
        {
            int countingValue = initialValue;
            delayMiliseconds = delayMiliseconds == 0 ? 1000 : delayMiliseconds;

            while (initialValue <= finalValue ? countingValue <= finalValue : countingValue >= finalValue)
            {
                Display(countingValue); //Função que fará o display da contagem

                await Task.Delay(delayMiliseconds);

                countingValue = initialValue <= finalValue ? countingValue + 1 : countingValue - 1;    
            }
        }
```

Leiam os seguintes posts se quiserem ter uma explicação mais detalhada acerca do assunto:

[Como fazer a aplicação esperar por um tempo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/86014/como-fazer-a-aplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-esperar-por-um-tempo)

[Como usar e pra que serve a função timer no C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/211902/como-usar-e-pra-que-serve-a-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-timer-no-c)

Créditos ao Maniero♦.