# Função que recebe outra função como parâmetro em C#

Tags: c#, funções, lua, função-anônima

Na linguagem Lua tem como criar uma função que recebe como argumento outra função, por exemplo :

```
exemplo = function(outrafunction)
  outrafunction()
end

exemplo(function print("alguma coisa") end)
```

Tem alguma forma de fazer isso usando C#?

Comment: Eu mudei o título porque acho que ele não tinha nada a ver com a dúvida real, se errei me informe. A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 5):

Sua sintaxe está errada, mas tudo bem.

Em C# seria:

```
using System;
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() => Exemplo(() => WriteLine("alguma coisa"));
    public static void Exemplo(Action outraFunction) => outraFunction();
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/d6FfzX). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BV8vAh). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Lambda/Example.cs).

É essencialmente uma sintaxe diferente, mas o mecanismo é idêntico.

Answer (score 0):

É possível que esse Action seja do tipo bool ?
Sempre que tento  realizar essa mudança :
"`private void BuscarComprasASSD(string conta, Action Buscar, Action<bool> condicao )"`

Aparece esse erro:

```
 não há argumento fornecido que corresponde ao parâmetro formal necessário "obj" de Action<bool>
```

Answer (score 0):

Caso queiras que uma função seja passada por parâmetro de uma forma simples usar Action ou Func. A diferença entre as duas é que Action é do tipo void. Com Func podes ter um return type, e até 16 parâmetros de entrada.
No exemplo seguinte usei uma Action e uma Func para invocar uma função mas sá a func consegue retornar um valor.

Caso pretendas ter uma visão mais alargada podes ver como funcionam os  [delegates.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/using-delegates)

```
 public static void Main()
{
  Exemplo(() =>  IsLeapYear());
  Exemplo2(() => IsLeapYear());
  bool x = Exemplo3(()=> IsLeapYear());
  bool y = Exemplo3(() => IsLeapYear( DateTime.Now.Year));
}

public static void Exemplo(Action outraFuncao) => outraFuncao();
public static void Exemplo2(Func<bool> outraFuncao) => outraFuncao();
public static bool Exemplo3(Func<bool> outraFuncao) => outraFuncao();


private static bool IsLeapYear() => DateTime.IsLeapYear(DateTime.Now.Year);
private static bool IsLeapYear(int year) => DateTime.IsLeapYear(year);
```

Podes ver ainda esta resposta [que explica func e actions.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/90061/120295)