# Qual a diferença entre usar métodos normais e Action ou Func?

Tags: c#, .net, expressões-lambda, método

```
public Action<string> Escrever = (texto) => 
{
        Console.WriteLine(texto);

};
```

Podendo chamar assim

```
 Escrever.Invoke("Algum texto aqui dentro");
```

VS

```
public string Escrever(string texto)
{
   Console.WriteLine(texto);
}
```

Podendo chamar assim

```
Escrever("Algum texto aqui dentro");
```

ou ainda

```
public Func<int, int, int> Soma = (n1, n2) => {
    return n1 + n2;
};
```

Podendo chamar assim

```
Soma.Invoke(1,2);
```

VS

```
public int Soma(int n1, int n2)
{
   return n1 + n2;
}
```

Podendo chamar assim

```
Soma(1,2)
```

Em que situações devo usar umas e outras?

Qual as formas mais eficientes?

Comment: Eu acho que isso não tem a ver com método ser diferente, você está apenas definindo que o retorno de `Escrever` será da classe `Action` usando `string` como constraint.

Comment: O segundo caso, geralmente `Func` é usado para definir funções locais (ou anônimas, não sei bem como se chama em C#). Lembra muito as closures do PHP e javascript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Por padrão use métodos, ele tem a menor [indireção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101) possível. Se for um método estático ou de instância simples há apenas a indireção mínima necessária que é mandar para a parte do código onde ele está escrito ou até em alguns casos com otimizações ele pode até eliminar isso e copiar o código e ser mais rápido, fora que é um mecanismo bastante simples.

Quando precisa que o método seja personalizado em uma classe que deriva da sua aí precisa deixar o método `virtual`. Nesse caso praticamente impede a otimização e existe um nível extra de indireção para descobrir qual é o tipo concreto do objeto antes de decidir que método chamar, se é da classe base ou derivada. Isso é o tal do [polimorfismo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/153042/101).

Mas pode ser que precise de uma personalização maior, pode querer que cada instâncias do objeto tenha uma ação personalizada naquele método, não basta só deixar a classe derivada personalização a implementação do método. Nesse caso você precisa ter uma infraestrutura dentro da instância que controle isso, e é aí que o método anônimo entra.

Esta forma criar uma variável que é de um tipo `delegate`, então ela é um indireção extra como o `virtual` é, e hoje nunca pode ser otimizado, mesmo no futuro poucos casos seriam possíveis e com custo alto para o compilador.

Feito isto você tem a implementação do campo `Escrever` ou `Soma` como um objeto que terá como seu valor básico a implementação de um método, que nada mais é que um corpo de um método normal, mas ele não terá um nome vinculado nele estaticamente.

Desta forma você pode criar um objeto e colocar a implementação que quiser e mudar a execução. Pode determinar um jeito diferente de fazer a tal escrita ou soma que é para fazer. Pode inclusive trocar no meio da execução. Na forma declarada, o valor está livre para ser trocado, assim como uma variável qualquer do tipo `int` ou `string`, então pode mandar dizer que "agora" o método a ser executado tem outra implementação, por exemplo:

```
objeto.Escrever => Write($"Tenho um texto para te dizer: {texto}");
```

Isso não executará nada, só mudará o valor do campo `Escrever`. Para executar isso tem que chamar:

```
objeto.Escrever()
```

Não é necessário usar o `Invoke()`.

Em geral você não quer que a implementação seja mudada no objeto no meio da sua execução, então pode fazer assim:

```
public readonly Action<string> Escrever;
```

E depois no construtor fazer algo assim:

```
this.Escrever = (texto) => WriteLine(texto);
```

O `this` provavelmente não é necessário, foi mais para ilustrar.

Se fizer só

```
public readonly Action<string> Escrever = (texto) => WriteLine(texto);
```

não faz sentido, neste caso é melhor usar um método normal, afinal você não pode personalizar em nenhum momento que seria o objetivo disto.

E se fizer

```
public static readonly Action<string> Escrever = (texto) => WriteLine(texto);
```

aí é só um jeito muito mais complicado e ineficiente de fazer

```
public void Escrever(texto) => WriteLine(texto);
```

Tem algumas perguntas que explicam melhor o mecanismo interno da função anônima, principalmente me [c](/questions/tagged/c). E tem também outras que falam sobre o carregamento de variáveis em clausura.

Ambos podem usar a sintaxe tipo *lambda* (`=>`) e tornar o código menos verboso.

```
public Func<int, int, int> Soma = (n1, n2) => n1 + n2;

public int Soma(int n1, int n2) => n1 + n2;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Lambda/ActionFunc.cs).

Veja mais em:

- [Qual a diferença entre Action, Predicate e Func](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90058/101)
- [Qual a diferença entre uma expressão lambda, um closure e um delegate?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/34907/101)
- [Qual é a finalidade do operador => no uso de listas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/99379/101)
- [Quando e onde usar um delegate no C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101238/101)
- [Delegates e métodos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/116095/101)
- [Qual a diferença entre event e delegate?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56957/101)
- [Protótipo de funções em C/C++](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/322422/101)
- [Polimorfismo em linguagem procedural](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53108/101)

Comment: public int Soma(int n1, int n2) => n1 + n2; Só se aplica quando apenas tem uma linha?

Comment: Sim, embora dê pra usar algum truque para mais, mas é abuso.

Comment: mostra então :)

Comment: Serei processado por atentado ao puder :D